# Mount-ing a CDROM repo during docker build

Tags: docker, mount

I'm building a docker image which also involves a small `yum install`. I'm currently in a location where firewall's and access controls makes `docker pull`, `yum install` etc extremely slow.

In my case, its a JRE8 docker image using this [official image script](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleJava)

**My problem:**

Building the image requires just 2 libraries (gzip + tar) which combined is only of (132 kB + 865 kB). But the yum inside docker build script will first download the repo information which is over 80 MB. While 80 MB is generally small, here, this took over 1 hour just to download. If my colleagues need to build, this would be sheer waste of productive time, not to mention frustration.

**Workarounds I'm aware of:**

- Since this image may not need the full yum power, I can simply grab the *.rpm files, `COPY` in container script and use `rpm -i` instead of `yum`
- I can save the built image and locally distribute
- I could also find closest mirror for docker-hub, but not yum

**My bet:**

- I've copy of the linux CD with about the same version
- I can add commands in dockerfile to rename the *.repo to *.repo.old
- Add a cdrom.repo in /etc/yum.repos.d/ inside the container
- Use yum to load most common libraries from the CDROM instead of internet

**My problem:**

I'm not able to make out how to create a mount point to a cdrom repo from inside the container build without using httpd.

In plain linux I do this:

```
mkdir /cdrom
mount /dev/cdrom /cdrom

cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/cdrom.repo <<EOF
[cdrom]
name=CDROM Repo
baseurl=file:///cdrom
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///cdrom/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
EOF
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: do you have an internal docker registry?

Comment: @YuriG. No internal docker registry, with much efforts using a nearby docker mirror works albeit slow. But this issue is with yum repository of which there are no mirrors nearby.

Comment: did you try to mount the cdrom on the host machine and  copy the files from the mounted folder?

Comment: @YuriG. I can do this, but if there are package dependencies (none in this specific case though), the rpm execute will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker containers cannot access host devices. I think you will have to write a wrapper script around the docker build command to do the following

1. First mount the CD ROM to a directory within the docker context ( that would be a sub-directory where your DockerFile exists).
2. call docker build command using contents from this directory
3. Un-mount the CD ROM.

so,

```
cd docker_build_dir
mkdir cdrom
mount /dev/cdrom cdrom
docker build "$@" .
umount cdrom
```

In the DockerFile, you would simple do this:

```
RUN cd cdrom && rpm -ivh rpms_you_need
```

Comment: The only problem I would note is, if the packages have dependencies the rpm execute would fail. Anyway I can find dependencies for now, accepting your answer.